# Help with Android XML layout

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to get my xml to lay this out properly.  How it is now, the video is mooshed.  If I take away the

```
android:layout_below="@id/day_scroller"
```

in the VideoView tag and add

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

the video size is now proportioned, but I lose my content that is display in my

```
android:id="@+id/day_container"
```

I did not create this layout, but am trying to understand how layouts work and to get this one to work properly.  Any help or leads to where I can gain a better understanding is greatly appreciated!

Here is what I want:
[image]

And here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
>
   <com.accuweather.wordweather.SnapHorizontalScrollView android:id="@+id/day_scroller"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dip"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    >
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/day_container"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="45dip"
        />    
   </com.accuweather.wordweather.SnapHorizontalScrollView>
   <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/location"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:textSize="20dip"
    />      
<ImageView android:id="@+id/current_alert_icon"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:src="@drawable/alert_icon"
       android:visibility="gone"
       />
<VideoView android:id="@+id/videoview" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    /> 

<ProgressBar android:id="@+android:id/progress_large"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    />

<LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_marginBottom="4dip"
     >
     <ImageView android:id="@+id/scroll_page_1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:src="@drawable/scrollview_page_on"
         />
     <ImageView android:id="@+id/scroll_page_2"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:src="@drawable/scrollview_page_off"
         />

     <ImageView android:id="@+id/scroll_page_3"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:src="@drawable/scrollview_page_off"
         />
 </LinearLayout>

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo" 
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
    android:src="@drawable/logo"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
    android:layout_width="150dip"
    android:layout_height="13dip"
    />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/logo_mask"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
    android:layout_width="180dip"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:background="@drawable/trans"
    />
```

Comment: It would help if you gave a screenshot of what you mean by smooshed

Answer (score 0):

You could use a LinearLayout with android:orientation="vertical" and store everything in it : all of the LinearLayout's children will be arranged vertically.

Comment: I tried this and lost my horizontal linear layout that has my page count image displays.  I nested this inside the vertical layout.